# How to Download Embed PDF File While Button Clicked Using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an **Embed PDF** File inside **object HTML** Tag it shows up well what I want to achieve is I have an external HTML Button While I clicked on it it will download the Embed PDF in my computer using jQuery and display a success download message using **SweatAlert2 Plugin**.

**HTML :**

```
<object data="myfile.pdf" class="w-100" height="665"></object>
<button type="button" id="downloadButton" class="btn btn-primary">Download PDF</button>
```

**JS :**

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $("#downloadButton").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Swal.fire({
            icon: "success",
            title: "The file is downloaded successfully!",
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500,
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

> Note: I know that the download button already exists in embed PDF but
> I want to create an external one with my custom design.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an example from GitHub, it works. https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

```
(function ($) {
"use strict";
$("#downloadButton").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
// Use File saver code by following https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js
    Swal.fire({
        icon: "success",
        title: "The file is downloaded successfully!",
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500,
    });
}) })(jQuery);
```

Comment: can you help please I don't know how to use the file saver for PDF file?

Comment: Please checkout this link https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Comment: Did you understand how can use File Saver?